# Choosing the right coordinate system to measure area all over the world

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, google-earth-engine

I'm kind of new to GIS, I have a background in physics, but I'm pretty confused with all the projection available and how to use them.

I have a dataset of 133 coordinates around the world. I am using the Hansen forest cover dataset
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UMD_hansen_global_forest_change_2021_v1_9, which I binarized in order to have a categorical landcover map.

I want to compute several landscape metrics using the "landscapemetrics" package in R, typically in a buffer circle of 10km around my points. The landscape metrics include patch areas, edge lengths and other metrics that use area and distance.

For each site, I extracted the circular image from GEE, using the "projection" of the original Hansen dataset: EPSG:4326, which is more like a geodetic system than a projection, if I understood well, since its units are in degrees and not in meters.

```
var projection = Hansen.projection().getInfo(); //get the projection (EPSG:4326)
var circle = my_coordinates.buffer({'distance': 10000});
  
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: Hansen,
  description: 'my_image',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: circle
});
```

[image: One of my forest cover images]

The problem is, I need a CRS with unit in meters in order to compute my metrics. Coming from physics, where we use spherical coordinates a lot, I would just apply a simple scaling to convert degrees to meters (depending on the latitude of my coordinates of course, e.g. by using the haversine formula), but this solution gets too inaccurate at larger scales. In any case, it seems more reasonable to reproject my original data, either in GEE before exporting, or in R before computing the metrics.

I have tried reprojecting in R in several projections (kind of random, e.g. EPSG:4088 or EPSG:3857), using the `projectRaster()` function:

```
epsg4088 = '+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007 +b=6371007 +units=m +no_defs'
reprojected_raster <- projectRaster(original_raster, crs = epsg4088)
```

It seems to work, and I manage to compute the landscape metrics, but they seem to vary a lot depending on which projection I'm choosing. For example, the very simple metric giving me the total area of my circle varies by up to 10%.

I'm also not sure to understand what happens to the raster when I reproject. Intuitively, I thought of the projection as some kind of external property to my raster that I can change easily without loss/modification of information. I would expect the raster data (pixels) to remain exactly the same, and I would see the CRS as some kind of "property" of the raster, which allows to say "pixel number (...) corresponds to coordinate (...), is (...)m wide and (...)m high.
But looking at the raster data, it actually gets modified (in dimensions, resolution and values) and I wonder according to what rule my pixels are modified. Here is my original raster object and the ones for EPSG:4088 and EPSG:3857, they are clearly different:

```
#original (units in degrees)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 720, 775, 558000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.00025, 0.00025  (x, y)
extent     : -43.78875, -43.595, -22.665, -22.485  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)


#epsg:4088 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 730, 785, 573050  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 27.8, 27.8  (x, y)
extent     : -4869231, -4847408, -2520376, -2500082  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)


#epsg:3857 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 731, 786, 574566  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 27.8, 30.1  (x, y)
extent     : -4874680, -4852830, -2591708, -2569705  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -0.0003438004, 1.00033  (min, max)
```

This all seems a bit confusing, and my problem probably lies in the fact that I don't understand coordinates systems and transformations that well. Maybe my main question is: is it possible to just transform a raster with units in degrees to a raster with units in meters, without changing my data? And is this something recommended?

If not, then my question is: Which projection should I use for global datasets? I need something quite accurate in area and distance in all my study locations (in forests around the world), because I will have to compare the 133 studies.

EDIT: From the comments, it seems like I should use the transverse Mercator projection. I was thinking of using the longitude of each of my points point for the central meridian to have maximum accuracy, but I guess using the UTM zones is good enough for my scale (usually less than 1° in both longitude and latitude).

It becomes a bit clearer to me now why I was (and still am a bit) confused about doing distance and area measurements.

**Distance:**
If we admit that the earth is a perfect sphere (or even ellipsoid), shouldn't we be able to measure perfectly any distance between two coordinates (WGS84) by using great circles? In this case, we wouldn't need to worry about any projection.

**Area:**
I feel like there must be a way to measure areas with an arbitrary precision too, since in the end any surface (let's say a forest patch) is a fraction of the area of an ellipsoid, which we can compute mathematically too. For example, in the discrete case, I could take the grid of the raster of my dataset and assign an area to each of the cells (using some formula for the area of rectangles on a sphere), and then use this "area grid" as weights that I can multiply with my 2D Hansen forest cover raster.

So I'm still wondering why we need to use projections to calculate distances and areas. From what I understand, Euclidean distances and areas measured *directly on the flat projection* must always have an error, but then why do we even try? Isn't it "easier" and more accurate to measure distances and areas directly on the ellipsoid?

Comment: Convert to fitting local UTM strips, then calculate areas. There's no global CRS which returns reliable area & distance measurements.

Comment: There isn't an EPSG CRS code 4088 according to the [Official EPSG registry](https://epsg.org/home.html)

Comment: If you want accurate distance and area, you want to stay *way* clear of Web Mercator (3587), which doesn't provide either, anywhere. If your coordinate density is sufficient, you could just use geodesic measurement tools, and avoid CRS selection issues, entirely.

Comment: For area calculations use an equal area projection like World Cylindrical Equal Area